# How to duplicate HTML element using JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Edited, to provide more information

This is my HTML

```
<div class="quote-info">
        <div class="quote-item">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="list-item1">Item</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <label for="quantity-item1">Quantity</label>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <label for="price-item1">Price</label>
                    <input type="number" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                    <label for="total-item1">Total</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <button class="btn add-item"> 
        New Item
    </button>
```

// Javascript

```
var quoteInfo = document.querySelector('div.quote-info')

var newDiv = quoteInfo.lastElementChild


var addButton = document.querySelector('.add-item')

addButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
    quoteInfo.appendChild(newDiv.cloneNode())
})
```

I'm trying to make the button to be clickable and create a new div of `<quote-item>` inside of `<quote-info>` but nothing happen

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Please show what you tried that only created one. The objective here is for you to show your attempts and others help modify your code , not to do all the code writing for you

Comment: Using `.cloneNode` will let you do what you seem to be describing. I have a feeling there was something else wrong.

Comment: @charlietfl Sorry, it was my first post, I work it out now with code provided by Abito,
`.cloneNode` also works too, the issue that cause my question is that i misplaced the code with DOM selector in my JS file. Thank you so much guys

Comment: No worries. Asking here has a learning curve. Keep in mind that even when your code doesn't work you learn more by people pointing out why so don't be shy to post it

Comment: @charlietfl Can you help me with my new format code? I tries to apply the code from yesterday with my actual code but it doesn't work. Can you point me where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use
[Document.createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) to create the input tag and then append it to the target div by using [Node.appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)

```js
var container= document.querySelector(".your-cart");
var input = document.createElement("input");
input.type = "text";
input.className = "item"; 
container.appendChild(input);
```

Comment: Can you help with the updated code?

Now it doesn't work at all :/

Comment: The function is getting executed correctly and quote-item is added, but it is empty. For cloneNode if we pass the optional parameter deep as true, then node and its whole subtree is also copied. So try with ````quoteInfo.appendChild(newDiv.cloneNode(true))````

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned that you tried `after()` and `cloneNode()`. There's no `after()` method for DOM elements, but there is `appendChild()`. So that may have been your mistake.

```js
const div = document.querySelector("div.your-cart")
const input = div.firstElementChild;
const button = document.querySelector("button.new-item")

button.addEventListener("click", event =>
  div.appendChild(input.cloneNode())
)
```

```html
<div class="your-cart">
  <input class="item" type="text">
  <input class="item" type="text">
</div>


<button class="new-item">CLICK ME</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

hi you can do it like below with jquery:

1- raw html injection like so:

```
$('.your-cart').append('<input class="item" type="text"/>');
```

2- using existing element:

```
var $input = $('.your-cart').children().eq(0).clone();
 $('.your-cart').append($input);
```

you can add as much as element you need  to '.your-cart'

Comment: Need to remove the `[0]` after children() or will throw error as that returns the underlying native element which has no `clone()` method. Alternatives are `.eq(0)` or `.first()`

Comment: Why jQuery? This is a simple task, and jQuery at this point is little more than bloat added to your code.

Comment: jquery is better in syntax, and about [0] your right

Comment: Heavy price to pay for what is today at best a moderate improvement in syntax.

Comment: if you search you can see a lot of reason for using jquery:

Comment: http://www.lucemorker.com/blog/javascript-vs-jquery-quick-overview-and-comparison#:~:text=jQuery%20in%20terms%20of%20speed,So%20is%20pure%20JavaScript.&text=Pure%20Javascript%20to%20access%20the,that%20slow%20things%20down%20again.

Comment: With JavaScript, one needs to handle multiple- browser compatibilities by writing their own code- With JQuery, as we all know that it is a multi-browser library

Comment: and also this question in stack over flow show jquery advatage some how